# Not able to find Cs Cart structure files

Tags: php, cs-cart

I am new to cs cart so can anyone please let me know under which folder i can see the code files like the header and the footer files.
There are so many folders under cs cart and i have tried finding it under skins folder but still no success.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use "Design Mode" to see which template you need to edit.

- in cscart 4: `Design->template editor->settings icon->on-site template editing`
- in cscart < 4: `Design->design mode->customization mode button`

When you turn on this modes you will be able to see icon hints on the storefront

Answer (score 1):

To find `Header`

```
/skins/basic/customer/top.tpl
```

Comment: hi i have made required changes to the top.tpl but its not showing on live.
i need to add some div tags into the current structure.
can you please guide me on this as i will be very thankful to you.